# how to delete element using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 <ul>
    <li>
         <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control"> 
         <option value="46_34" selected="selected">10X20</option>                                                                   
         <option value="47_24">10X18</option>
         <option value="48_25">10X15</option></select>
   </li>
   <li>
        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control **changed**">
        <option value="49_32" selected="selected">1-40</option>
        <option value="50_31">1-20</option></select>
   </li>
   <li>
        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
        <option value="51_26" selected="selected">Glossy</option>
        <option value="52_27">Matte</option></select>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here the class name 'changed' added to the only after change the value of the corresponding select box through the below code.

```
$('select').on("change", function () {
  $(this).addClass("changed");
});
```

After changing the value I need to delete the following 'li' block of the 'li' that contains 'select' having class  'changed' .In the above case the last 'li' block.How can I achieve this.I tried

```
$('.changed').parent().siblings().after().remove();
```

But it also deleting the above 'li' too.

Comment: use `$('.changed').parents("li:first").remove();`.

Comment: run snippet. check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.changed').parent().next().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('.changed').closest("li").remove();
```

This will remove the li which contains the element with the class name  `changed`

`closest()` method will get the parent element specified in it.

**Edit**

If you want to delete the next li, you need to use,

```
$('.changed').closest("li").next().remove();
```

Comment: closet traverse above, it will remove self/previous parent. she want to remove next/following, i believe Sanchit is right here

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the last li element.

```
$('li:last').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').on("change", function () {
  $(this).addClass("changed");
  $('.changed').parents("li:first").next().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
         <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control"> 
         <option value="46_34" selected="selected">10X20</option>                                                                   
         <option value="47_24">10X18</option>
         <option value="48_25">10X15</option></select>
   </li>
   <li>
        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control **changed**">
        <option value="49_32" selected="selected">1-40</option>
        <option value="50_31">1-20</option></select>
   </li>
   <li>
        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
        <option value="51_26" selected="selected">Glossy</option>
        <option value="52_27">Matte</option></select>
   </li>
</ul>
```

You have to do

```
$('.changed').parents("li:first").next().remove();
```

this will remove the li which contains the element with the class name changed

Comment: she want next/followed li do be removed.

Comment: @AnilKumar  Ok sorry i missunderstood

Comment: @neethu do upvote and mark as anwer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("body").on("click",".changed", function(e){ 
            $(this).parentsUntil('.yourclass').remove();   
    });
```